# Home Page content not showing in Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am using codazon theme for my Magento store. The home page content is not displaying.

Previously it was working fine. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Kindly check Magento log files for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why the content on your home page may not be displaying. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check if the content is enabled: Make sure that the content you want to display on your home page is enabled. To do this, go to your Magento admin panel and navigate to Content > Pages > Home Page. Then, click on the Content tab and ensure that the content is enabled.
2. Clear cache: It is possible that the content is not displaying due to cached files. To clear the cache, go to System > Cache Management in your Magento admin panel and click on the Flush Magento Cache button.
3. Check for conflicts: Sometimes, there can be conflicts with other extensions or modules that may be preventing your content from displaying. Try disabling any recently installed extensions or modules to see if that resolves the issue.
4. Check for errors: Check your server error logs to see if there are any errors that may be causing the content to not display. If there are any errors, try fixing them or consult with your hosting provider or developer for further assistance.